# Join array elements, display only lowest value

Tags: php, arrays

My array:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[20]
      public 'PkID' => string '488' (length=3)
      public 'Price' => string '666' (length=3)
      public 'discount_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[38]
      public 'PkID' => string '490' (length=3)
      public 'Price' => string '999' (length=3)
      public 'discount_id' => string '2' (length=1)
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[41]
      public 'PkID' => string '489' (length=3)
      public 'Price' => string '111' (length=3)
      public 'discount_id' => string '1' (length=1)
```

Question is how can I group elements together that share the same `discount_id` number. But when I group, I wish that only the lowest `Price` integer is displayed.

EDIT: I tried

```
foreach ($array as $value)
{
     $new_array[$value->discount_id] = $value;
}
```

Which returns grouped arrays like so:

```
array (size=2)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[41]
      public 'PkID' => string '489' (length=3)
      public 'Price' => string '111' (length=3)
      public 'discount_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[38]
      public 'PkID' => string '490' (length=3)
      public 'Price' => string '999' (length=3)
      public 'discount_id' => string '2' (length=1)
```

But I don't know how to display the smallest price from those two grouped elements (in the example above it is the smallest but this is only coincidence)

Comment: Start with writing code. No one will do it for you.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. (Some PHP code)

Comment: Is your data from a database? If so you could group it during the SQL query.

Comment: can you show the approximate expected output?

Comment: Way to make a last minute save right before the question gets shut down. Nice work!

Comment: @Mad Physicist thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
$new_array = array();
foreach ($array as $value) {
    if (array_key_exists($value->discount_id, $new_array)) { // element with given discount_id already exists
        if ($new_array[$value->discount_id]->Price > $value->Price) { // existing element has higher price - replace it
            $new_array[$value->discount_id] = $value;
        }
    } else { // add new element
       $new_array[$value->discount_id] = $value;
    }
}
```

simplified:

```
$new_array = array();
foreach ($array as $value)
    if (!array_key_exists($value->discount_id, $new_array) || $new_array[$value->discount_id]->Price > $value->Price) // no element or existing element has higher price
       $new_array[$value->discount_id] = $value;
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir for you answer but how am I suppose to check `array_key_exists` if  `$new_array` is not existing yet